# Unable to pass values to MVC Controller via AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller which takes an int and a complex object

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> AddComment(int ticketId, TicketReply ticketReply)
```

Even if I take out the object, I can't seem to pass a simple value. Here's what the AJAX call looks like

```
var dataObject = {
    ticketId: ticketId //, ticketReply: { Attachements: attachements }
};

$.ajax({
    url: $('#updateTicketURL').val(),
    data: dataObject, //, //JSON.stringify(dataObject),  //JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    type: 'POST',
    //dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    }
})
```

I have tried every combination of `JSON.stringyfy` etc. but I never seem to get the value. Even if I replace with static values it never seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object model that matches the data being sent

```
public class DataObject {
    public int ticketId { get; set; }
    public TicketReply ticketReply { get; set; }
}
```

next you update the controller action to expect the data using the `[FromBody]` attribute so that the model binder can create and populate the sent data

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> AddComment([FromBody]DataObject dataObject) {

    int ticketId = dataObject.ticketId;
    TicketReply ticketReply = dataObject.ticketReply;

    //...
}
```

Finally you need to send the data correctly from the client.

```
var dataObject = {
    ticketId: ticketId , 
    ticketReply: { Attachements: attachements }
};

$.ajax({
    url: $('#updateTicketURL').val(),
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```